# Magus Spell combat work with spells from other classes

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was wanting to play a Magus/wizard, and was wondering if spell combat would work with spells from both classes?

Comment: Just as an aside, I'd not recommend multiclassing magus/wizard; you're not doing either class a favour like that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Sort of.**

Only spells that are on the *magus list* that the character has memorised (from any class, so Wizard counts) can be used in spell combat. The quote is:

> As a full-round action, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty **and can also cast any spell from the magus spell list** with a
>   casting time of 1 standard action (any attack roll made as part of
>   this spell also takes this penalty).

Now I'd normally interpret this as any "magus spells" but we're going for Rules as Written here, so...

The magus spell list includes a lot of wizard spells, as the magus gets their spells from the core wizard list anyway but some wizard spells will NOT be a magus spell, so they can't be used.

However there is one more major problem. *[A multiclass magus still incurs the normal arcane spell failure chance for arcane spells received from other classes.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcasters/magus.html)*

So if the magus has any armour on when they try to cast their Wizard spells as spell combat, they'll get a spell failure chance, which isn't worth going for, believe me.

That all said; it's really not worth multiclassing wizard/magus - stick with just one!

Also as mentioned there is a [Magus Arcana Broad Study](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/broad-study-ex) which allows use of spells from another *class* in spellstrike. So despite the bad wording in the original text it does appear the *intent* is that only the spells memorised as a magus should be used, but above is strictly RAW.

Comment: If you could cast a spell, as a Wizard, that is also on the Magus Spell List, you would be able to use it with Spell Combat based on the rules you’ve quoted.

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe that's the intent of it - but with RAW I see the point, I will change...

Comment: Remember Rob, RAW doesn't care about things like 'intent' or 'sanity'.

Comment: They are vastly overrated :)

Comment: One point - Bards and Sorcerers don't memorise spells...

Comment: Corrected, ta @YugoZuno

Comment: There's a Magus Arcana, Broad Study, that allows a Magus to use Spellstrike and Spell Combat with spells from other classes. I agree that by RAW you could use Wizard spells that are on the Magus spell list, but by RAI you would need to get Broad study first